# something is using my sound interface?

Tags: windows-7, audio

I am using an M-Audio Fast Track MkII
All of a sudden, it is being used by something. As soon as I boot up, the mic is on, and I can't change settings or access the interface in Live.

The change was having an audio streaming packing installed, but I have since uninstalled that package.

I can't see anything in the process list that would be using the interface.

How can I figure out what is using it? Hoe can I get control back?

thanks

EDIT : My apologies - I am running Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: You did not identify the operating system?  in a windows system you could try AutoRuns, then look in the codecs (and filters) section. and In the services section you could look for a service.  In this situation it would be easier to make sure that microsoft&windows entries stay hidden in the options.

Comment: edited... sorry for that

Comment: (sorry for this, but...) I think it's the FBI...